# how list all content in a subdirectory with it's size

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Write a shell script that takes a name of a folder as a command line argument, and produces a file that contains the names of all subdirectories with size 0. This is what I have so far.

```
echo 'folder name'
read folder 
ls -l sheet.txt
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Are you allowed to use any standard Unix tool? The `du` command should be helpful.

Comment: i thought of the du command.

Comment: What do you mean by a *directory with size 0*?  Do you mean that it contains no files?  Or that it has no filesystem blocks at all?  Or that that the files it contains have no data?  As it is, there are different answers depending on which definition you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define "size 0", this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
du $1 | awk '$1 == 0 { print $2 }'
```

Comment: You're right to point out that there's more than one way to define the "size" of a directory!

Answer (score -1):

```
files=(`ls`)
for file in ${files[@]}
do
        size=(`stat --printf="%s\n" $file`)
        if [ $size -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo $file
        fi
done
```

And you chenge standard output stream to file, and result of this script will write to file. And wrap this cript to function and with recursion go through all subdirectories.
If you need I can write full code.

Recursion code:

```
function search {
    cd $1
    files=(`ls`)
    for file in ${files[@]}
    do
        type=(`stat --printf="%F\n" $file`)
        if [ "$type" == "directory" ]
        then
            search $file
        else
            size=(`stat --printf="%s\n" $file`)
            if [ $size -eq 0 ]
            then
                    echo $file
            fi
        fi
    done
    cd ..
}

search .
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is robust when filenames may contain space or newline characters?  As it is, you seem to be iterating over the output of `ls`, which is a notoriously fragile anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, It's problem. But you can use another delimiter to split filenames.